# How do I assign different widths to edges considering the weight of correlations in igraph?

Tags: r, width, igraph

I need to change the width of the edges, to correspond to the weight of the corrections: Being width 1, correlation >7, width 2, correlation >8, width 3, correlation greater than 9.

Here is an example data set

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(62)
N <- 7
fakecors <- runif(choose(N, 2))
cormat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- fakecors
diag(cormat) <- 0
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(t(cormat))]
matrixnetwork <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cormat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
```

Trying this, forms:

```
E(matrixnetwork)$width <- 3*E(matrixnetwork)$weight

E(matrixnetwork)[weight >= 0.7 & weight < 0]$width <- 2
E(matrixnetwork)[weight >= 0.8 & weight < 0.7]$width <- 4
E(matrixnetwork)[weight >= 0.9 & weight < 0.8]$width <- 8

E(matrixnetwork)$width <- ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.8, '3', '2')#configurar por espessura
E(matrixnetwork)$width <- ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.9, '5', '3')#configurar por espessura

 E(matrixnetwork)$width <- ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.7, '1',
                      ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight > 0.79, '3','1',
                      ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight > 0.89, '5', '3')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be correct:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(62)
N <- 7
fakecors <- runif(choose(N, 2))
cormat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- fakecors
diag(cormat) <- 0
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(t(cormat))]
matrixnetwork <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cormat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)

# Set edge widths based on weight criteria
E(matrixnetwork)$width <- ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.9, 3,  # width 3 for weight >= 0.9
                                 ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.8, 2,  # width 2 for weight >= 0.8
                                        ifelse(E(matrixnetwork)$weight >= 0.7, 1,  # width 1 for weight >= 0.7
                                               0)))  # Default width (0) for other cases

# Plot the network to visualize the edge widths
plot(matrixnetwork)
```

[image]

Comment: it was just a small detail in the ifelse value assignments, you are incredible! Thanks!!